# break out of for loop if no checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a list of students with checkboxes alongside each of them. Now, i have to run a batch process but before sending that request i need to be able to proceed the request only if at least one checkbox is checked.

My JS function code so far is:

```
function batchOPTAllocate(){
var pid = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('alOptList').value);
var proceed = 0;
var elements = document.getElementsByName('stid[]');  
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
if (elements[i].checked){ 
    data.push('stid[]='+elements[i].value);
} else{
    proceed = 1;
    alert("You are required to select at least one student.");
    break;

        }
    }
if(proceed === 0){
params = "&paper="+pid+"&"+data.join('&');

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
// some code here...
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","batch.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(params);

}

}
```

With the above code even, if one of the checkbox is checked it is still giving the alert.

Comment: Could you explain what `stid[]` stands for in this line `var elements = document.getElementsByName('stid[]'); ` Is this an array which contains all names of the students and your checkboxes look like this `<input type="checkbox" name="Student_1" value="Suzy Vega" >`?

If you could add some of your html it would also be usefull.

Comment: yes, it is an array and the checkboxes look the same with a minor change in the name than what you think it is. it is `name="stid[]"` instead of `name=stid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are adding elements to the array `data` if an item is checked. Why not just move the alert out of the for loop and call it only if the length of `data` is zero?

Something like this:

```
if(data.length == 0)
{
    // alert
}else{
    // carry on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will alert if even just one checkbox is not checked because all it takes is to get into your else block once and proceed will no longer be 0

Comment: well, that i know. Can you please advise how to fix this?

Comment: follow jeremynealbrown's advice and check the length of data after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit skewed as it aborts on the first non-check item

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  if (elements[i].checked){ 
    data.push('stid[]='+elements[i].value);
  } else{
    proceed = 1;
    alert("You are required to select at least one student.");
    break;
  }
}
```

I would use:

```
var proceed = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  if (elements[i].checked){ 
    data.push('stid[]='+elements[i].value);
    proceed++;
  } 
}
if( proceed != 0 ) {
    alert("You are required to select at least one student.");
    break;
} else {
  //--- process students
}
```